# Load testing after 5minutes MySQL Access denied for user 'root'@'

Tags: mysql

We are running a load test using Loadrunner, for the first 5 minutes, everything was great but after 1600vus, I saw the MySQL log file contains the Access denied for user 'root'@'ip error.

Anybody have any idea what could this be the caused?

Answer (score 1):

You have exhausted a resource related to a connection session(?)   Take a look at your file descriptors/donnection handles in use and start working your way back from there.   BE aggressive in your session timeout and recovery of resources or you can start stacking up sessions in use over multiple iterations of your virtual user, exhausting your stack and coming to a halt.

Another question to ask, do you have think time or any iteration pacing in your test?  if not, it is time to revise that thinking.  The client-server model is built upon a cooperative processing foundation that assumes a set of delays in communication between client and server.  By moving towards a zero think time/pacing interval you wind up collapsing the model for all users in all use at all times.   That makes the value of your test unusable for predictions of user behavior.

Comment: I disagree that a load test's data conducted without pacing is useless. If what you are doing is testing the limits or the resilience of your setup, it is the right choice of test sets to run.

Comment: Look at the TPC-C benchmark as an example. No pacing: Fails Audit. If you are reproducing human behavior, then think time and pacing is part of the load model.   Look at the concept of a stress test, which takes the user behavior model and steps up the user load in a defined increment (with business process pacing/Think time) to the point of system exhaustion.   A look at the timestamps in your transaction log should show the relative spacing of queries from users in a high volume/high user system.  A great read on understanding natural systems is "Chaos: Making a new science" by James Gleick

Comment: The link to the current tpc-c is attached.  You can search for the tag 'think time' in the benchmark definition.  http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/spec/tpcc_current.pdf